# want to create dynamic html table in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am beginner in asp.net.I want to create dynamic html table for view data data come from database created in sql server.I fetch data from database and convert it in data set. Now i don't know how to display this data in html table.Each time numbers of data rows are different so i want to create dynamic html table according to data row each time.I need help. i am working on asp.net web forms.

Comment: i am working on web forms.

Comment: It's been a *long* time since I've used WebForms, but I suspect the control you're looking for is something like a `DataGrid` or a `GridView`?  If you want to really control the resulting HTML you might also just use a `Repeater`.  Each of these controls can be bound to a `DataTable` to dynamically render the data.  I imagine just about any WebForms tutorial you use would cover this, no?

Comment: i saw different tutorial but they always use data grid view instead of html table. i want to create a List  view like in  MVC. using foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to the question:

> i want to create a List view like in MVC. using foreach loop.

Well, there is no `ListView` in MVC.  (At least, I hope there isn't.)  `ListView` is a WebForms control just like `GridView` or `Repeater` or any other data-bound control that would do this.

If you just want to use a loop in the markup then you might be able to do that.  But at that point it begs the question... If you want to do things "the MVC way" then why not use MVC?  Use the framework that does what you want.

Regardless, you can access page-level properties in your markup as long as those properties aren't `private`.  So if you have a collection of objects in your page class:

```
protected IEnumerable<SomeType> SomeObjects { get; set; }
```

Then you can access that value in server-side code in the markup.  Potentially something like this:

```
<table>
<% foreach (var someObject in SomeObjects) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= someObject.SomeProperty %></td>
        <td><%= someObject.AnotherProperty %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

This is free-hand code, and as mentioned in a comment it's been a *long* time since I've had to use WebForms, but the concept should still be the same.  (Unless a lot has changed recently, which is certainly possible.)  My syntax might need a little work, so tweak as needed.

This would work for anything that can be enumerated.  So if you're using `DataSet` and `DataTable` objects instead of actual types (I recommend using actual types, for a whole host of reasons) then you can still enumerate the rows of the `DataTable` just like any other collection.